# How to make a new dependency task executes first than all other existed dependency tasks of the base task

Tags: android, gradle

I writes a demo build.gradle below:

```
task a << {
    println "this is task ${name}"
}
task b << {
    println "this is task ${name}"
}
task c << {
    println "this is task ${name}"
}
task d << {
    println "this is task ${name}"
}
task e << {
    println "this is task ${name}"
}
a.dependsOn(b)
e.dependsOn(a,d)

task f << {
    println "this is task ${name}"
}
e.dependsOn(f)
```

I run `gradle e` in cmd, the output is :

```
:b
this is task b
:a
this is task a
:d
this is task d
:f
this is task f
:e
this is task e
```

The task `e` depends on task `a` and `d`, then I add task `f` to `e`'s dependencies. Now the problem is how to make task `f` executes first. The expected output is like this:

```
:f
this is task f
:b
this is task b
:a
this is task a
:d
this is task d
:e
this is task e
```

I know here I can add `b.dependsOn(f)` to make task `f` execuse first. But assume I don't know what task `e` actually depends on, I only know the task `e` itself, can I make task `f` execuse first just through `e`'s methods?

I had refer the [Task](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.Task.html) API document, but I still don't know how to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved by myself.

add this block to the end of build.gradle

```
e.taskDependencies.getDependencies(e).each { task ->
    if (task != f) {
        task.mustRunAfter f
    }
}
```